# modify score for object to get the value 2400 and display it

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

[Hello I'm new to java , could u plz help me with this, I want to create an instance player in game class and modify score to get the value 2400 and display it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzvSy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is wrong. It shouldn't be score=0, it should be `this.score=score`

And it should also be `this.nom = nom`

Then you can just do

`Player player = new Player("nn", 2400)`

`System.out.println(player.toString())`

Comment: this.nom = nom   and   this.score = score
we already did that in function setNom and setScore
is it okay to do it again?

Comment: You can do it in the constructor if you know the values you're going to set while initializing the instance. If you don't know while initializing, that's when you use the setNom function. So, yeah it's ok to do it in both places